# Count Occurrences of All Integers in Matrix

Tags: r

I have an array containing 20,000 rows and 300 columns. Each element is an integer. I would like to count the occurrences of each integer in this matrix. [image]

I have tried the following:

```
 >frequency_Table=read.csv('huge_file.csv',header=FALSE,check.names=FALSE)
 >table(frequency_Table)
```

I get the error "attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements", which makes sense after reading it.

I want something like this:

```
1        2000
2        2023
3        5683
```

Basically, a frequency table of sorts, for all the numbers. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why this question is tagged Python?

Comment: You were effectively doing `table(column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,etc,etc)` which would be quickly apparent if you tried this on a smaller table first. That is the value of attempting to create a minimal example before posting on Stackoverflow - you often find an answer in the process of trying to put together a question.

Comment: I actually included python by accident, sorry about that. But the Python answers work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'frequency_table' object is a `data.frame`.  We `unlist` (assuming that the OP wants an `R` solution as the dataset got read with `R` syntax) it to make a `vector` and then get the frequency with `table`

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(frequency_table)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
frequency_table <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(22:29, 20*4, 
          replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
from numpy import np

Counter(np.array(frequency_Table).flatten())
```

Comment: You had tagged the question as Python and R. My answer was in Python. But looking again at your syntax it seems to me that your code is in R.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.unique` can do this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> table = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3]])
>>> values, counts = np.unique(table, return_counts = True)
>>> for value, count in zip(values, counts):
...     print("{}\t{}".format(value, count))
...
1       1
2       4
3       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you find out a way to get all the unique integers in the data.fame quickly?
My thought is that after you find out the unique integers in the data.frame. You can use the code `sapply(unique_int, function(x) sum(m == x))` to find out the corresponding occurrence of each integer.

This is the code I tried:

```
m <- matrix(sample(1:10, size=20000*300, replace=TRUE), ncol=300)
#A way to get the unique integers
unique_int <- unique(c(m))

#Count
count <- sapply(unique_int, function(x) sum(m == x))

names(count) <- unique_int
count

## 10      8      3      9      6      5      4      1      2      7 
## 598551 600413 599396 599517 600114 600503 601311 601205 599268 599722
```

Comment: From the response of @akrun, you can try `unique(unlist(your_dataframe))` to get the unique integers.

Answer (score 1):

Here a 1 line solution in R:
You can use stack() or unlist to arrange all columns of the dataset in one. Based on this you can define the first column of the the stacked dataset as factor and use tapply with length as a function, which gives you the frequency of each element:

Using stack():

```
tapply(stack(frequency_Table)[,1],factor(stack(frequency_Table)[,1]),length)
```

Using unlist:

```
tapply(unlist(frequency_Table),factor(unlist(frequency_Table)),length)
```